# How to use Java's Optional feature

Tags: java, functional-programming, nullpointerexception, java-stream, option-type

I have a use case and would like to know how to write it best using Java Optional so that I could reduce null checks?

```
// To get first residence place for family places or empty string if null
// What if familyPlaces is null?
public String getFirstResidencePlace(FamilyPlaces familyPlaces) {
    // What if getResidencePlaces() returns null in list?
    List<Place> places = familyPlaces.getResidencePlaces();
    for (Place place : places) {
        if (place.getResidencePlaces() != null &&
            !place.getResidencePlaces().isEmpty()) {
            return place.getResidencePlaces().toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Optional is usually used in cases where `null` is being used. In this case, you return the empty string, so your code won't benefit much from using Optional

Comment: You’d rather use it indirectly: `return familyPlaces.getResidencePlaces().stream().map(Place::getResidencePlaces) .filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).map(String::toLowerCase) .findAny().orElse("");` The even better solution would be to ensure that `getResidencePlaces` never returns `null`.

Comment: @smac89 If I'm understanding correctly what you said, how would it work if the return type was Optional<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be truly handled using `Optional` securing the cases the first called method results in the `null` value (`familyPlaces.getResidencePlaces()`):

**Java 9+**

```
Optional.ofNullable(familyPlaces.getResidencePlaces())        // Optional<List<Place>>
        .stream()                                             // Stream<List<Place>>
        .flatMap(list -> list.stream()
                             .map(Place::getResidencePlaces)) // Stream<String>
        .filter(res -> res != null && !res.isEmpty())         // Stream<String>
        .map(String::toLowerCase)                             // Stream<String>
        .findFirst()                                          // the first String found
        .orElse("");                                          // default return value
```

Note that the flatmapping is equal to:

```
.flatMap(List::stream)                    // from Stream<List<Place>> to Stream<Place>
.map(Place::getResidencePlaces)           // from Stream<Place> to Stream<String>
```

**Java 8:**

```
Optional.ofNullable(familyPlaces.getResidencePlaces())        // Optional<List<Place>>
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())                      // List<Place>
        .stream()                                             // Stream<Place>
        .map(Place::getResidencePlaces)                       // Stream<String>
        .filter(res -> res != null && !res.isEmpty())         // Stream<String>
        .map(String::toLowerCase)                             // Stream<String>
        .findFirst()                                          // the first String found
        .orElse("");                                          // default return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that makes greater use of Java's `Optional` feature by invoking the `map()` and `flatMap()` methods on `Optional` itself rather than on the `Stream` of `Place`s.

The following objects are null checked.

1. `familyPlaces`
2. the `getResidencePlaces` List
3. elements in the `getResidencePlaces` List
4. the `getResidencePlaces` String

   ```
   String firstPlace = Optional.ofNullable(familyPlaces)
           .map(FamilyPlaces::getResidencePlaces)
           .flatMap(places -> places.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst())
           .map(Place::getResidencePlaces)
           .map(String::toLowerCase)
           .orElse("");
   ```

This works in Java 8.

Comment: Flatmapping on `Optional` is a smart move. Have my +1